# GMSPolygon doesn't work in iOS Google Maps app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I have this code below for my new iOS Google Maps app. I can create dynamic markers on the map as the user taps on the screen but the polygon shape between the markers does not gets drawn. Any ideas why is this happening?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//Controls whether the My Location dot and accuracy circle is enabled.
CGFloat currentZoom = 14.0f;
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

//adds type of map: kGMSTypeSatellite, kGMSTypeTerrain, kGMSTypeHybrid, kGMSTypeNormal
self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;

//Shows the compass button on the map
self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;

//Shows the my location button on the map
self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

//Sets the view controller to be the GMSMapView delegate
self.mapView.delegate = self;
GMSCameraPosition *manhattan = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.790278
                                                        longitude:-73.959722
                                                             zoom:14];
self.mapView.camera = manhattan;
}
 //setting up zoom
-(void)ZoominOutMap:(CGFloat)level
{
self.mapView.delegate = self;
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.790218 longitude:-73.959722
                                                             zoom:level];
self.mapView.camera = camera;
}

-(void)zoomInMapView:(id)sender
{
CGFloat currentZoom;
currentZoom = currentZoom + 1;

[self ZoominOutMap:currentZoom];
}

-(void) zoomOutMapView:(id)sender
{
CGFloat currentZoom;
currentZoom = currentZoom - 1;

[self ZoominOutMap:currentZoom];
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
NSLog(@"You tapped at %f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
//adds animation for adding marker
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
//draw marker on tapped position
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude);
marker.map = _mapView;
//set color of marker and make them draggable
marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[marker setDraggable: YES];

// Create a rectangular path
GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)];

// Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect];
polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
polygon.strokeWidth = 2;
polygon.map = _mapView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not providing rectangular path. Add proper polygon coordinates to draw GMSPolygon

```
// Create a rectangular path
GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.36, -122.0)];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.45, -122.0)];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.45, -122.2)];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.36, -122.2)];

// Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect];
polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
polygon.strokeWidth = 2;
polygon.map = mapView;
```

Update:
Answer [How to insert array values to draw polygon based on long/lat values - Google Maps iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809299/how-to-insert-array-values-to-draw-polygon-based-on-long-lat-values-google-map/42809680?noredirect=1#comment72733015_42809680)

Comment: No, I do. Look: // Create a rectangular path
GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)];

Comment: @konyv12 Its single coordinate. For polygon you need to provide 4 or more coordinates.

Comment: How can I add that dynamically?

Comment: @konyv12 what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Draw the polygon as the user taps on the map.

Comment: @konyv12  why you want to draw polygon ? Do you have any shape for polygon ?   You can add marker instead of polygon drawing ?

Comment: The shape would be a polygon. With however many markers drawn (tapped) being the corners of that polygon. The user can already add markers by tapping, but I want the polygon to be drawn as long as they have tapped more than 2 (seeing 3 is the minimum number of coordinates u need to draw a polygon).

Comment: you have to store lat long of tapped location in array then pass array to the polygon. after 3 or more trapped location polygon will be drawn using user code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809299/how-to-insert-array-values-to-draw-polygon-based-on-long-lat-values-google-map

Answer (score 0):

You have to cut this line from 'didTapAtCoordinate' of code and paste it in `viewDidLoad`

```
#GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];#
```

Then it will work