# How to insert array values to draw polygon based on long/lat values - Google Maps iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I am trying the GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect]; method to draw a polygon of the tapped coordinates by the user. Here's how I store the clicked coordinates:

```
// array made of clicked coordinates
NSMutableArray *latitudeTappedCoordinates = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *longitudeTappedCoordinates = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger numberOfLongitudeCoordinates = [longitudeTappedCoordinates count];
NSUInteger numberOfLatitudeCoordinates = [latitudeTappedCoordinates count];
for (int i = 2; i < numberOfLatitudeCoordinates; i++) {
    [latitudeTappedCoordinates addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:coordinate.latitude]];
}
for (int i = 2; i < numberOfLongitudeCoordinates; i++) {
    [longitudeTappedCoordinates addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:coordinate.longitude]];
}
```

After this, I have the following:

```
// polygon
GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)];
GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect];
```

As you can see, the line

```
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)];
```

only takes in a single attribute. I want it to take in all the values in the arrays init above, so it can draw the polygon. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First store float values not int values in array.**
then

Add in interface

```
 NSMutableArray *latitudeTappedCoordinates;
 NSMutableArray *longitudeTappedCoordinates;
```

You can do like this :

```
// Create a rectangular path
GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];
CLLocationCoordinate2D event;

for (int i = 0; i <= [longitudeTappedCoordinates count]-1; i++) {
    event.latitude = [[latitudeTappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    event.longitude = [[longitudeTappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    [rect addCoordinate:event];
}

GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect];
polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
polygon.strokeWidth = 2;
polygon.map = mapView;
```

Comment: This is the error I got: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: I fixed it by initializing int i = 0 to int i = 1.

Comment: However, your code doesn't work; any ideas why? I keep adding the markers but the polygon does not gets drawn.

Comment: NO. make [longitudeTappedCoordinates count]-1

Comment: polygon.map = nil; after for loop.

Comment: @konyv12 You need to add NSMutableArray *latitudeTappedCoordinates and NSMutableArray *longitudeTappedCoordinates  in interface (global variable to class)